Alpine js not working or reinitialize after livewire load
I have added checkbox for single and multiple select using alpine js, but when livewire load it stops working abd getting this error . getting in the console.
Here is my code:
<div x-data="checkboxes()" 
     x-init="initCheckboxes({{ $products->pluck('id') }})" 
     class="min-w-full overflow-auto"
>
    
    <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200" 
           x-data="{ showSelected: false }" 
           style="table-layout: fixed;"
    >
        
        <thead class="bg-gray-50 sticky top-0">
        
            <tr> 
                
                <th class="px-1 py-1 text-left text-xs font-medium text-black uppercase tracking-wider">
                    
                    <label class="inline-flex items-center"> 
                        
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                               class="form-checkbox" 
                               @click="showSelected = !showSelected" 
                               x-on:click="toggleAll" 
                               x-bind:checked="allChecked"
                        >
                        
                    </label>
                
                </th>
            
            </tr>
        
        </thead>
        
        <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
        
            <tr>
                
                <td>
                    
                    <input type="checkbox" 
                           class="form-checkbox"
                           :checked="selectedProducts.includes({{ $product->id }})" 
                           @click="toggleProduct({{ $product->id }})"
                    >
                    
                </td>
                
            </tr>
        
        </tbody>
    
    </table>

    pluck('id') }})" class="min-w-full overflow-auto"\>

I want to resolve this error:
module.esm.js:566 Alpine Expression Error: toggleProduct is not defined   
    Expression: "toggleProduct(2371)"   
    module.esm.js:570 Uncaught   
    ReferenceError: toggleProduct is not defined  
    at [Alpine] toggleProduct(/2371) (eval at safe…), <anonymous>:3:16)  
        at eval (module.esm.js:644:21)`your text`  
        at tryCatch (module.esm.js:556:12)  
        at eval (module.esm.js:3325:5)  
        at handler4 (module.esm.js:2617:25)  
        at eval (module.esm.js:2682:5)  
        at HTMLInputElement.eval (module.esm.js:2619:52)  
        [Alpine] toggleProduct(2371) @ VM56660:3  
        Show 14 more frames


The simplest explanation is that there is no toggleProduct() function defined
You should show the checkboxes() function that defines the main Alpine object to give a more precise answer

I formatted your code better, it seems there is a misplaced pluck('id') }})" class="min-w-full overflow-auto"\>. Also I think you omitted the @foreach which makes up the lines of the .

On the checkbox in the table header you have both @click="showSelected = !showSelected" and x-on:click="toggleAll": they must be combined or one must be removed
